# Java Generics - Equality constraint in parameters

Tags: java, generics

Imagine the following class hierarchy:

```
Cake
\- ChocolateCake
  \- StuffedChocolateCake
\- VanillaCake
```

I want to write a method to combine Lists of ChocolateCake and VanillaCake, something like:

```
    public static <T extends Cake> List<T> union(List<T> listA, List<T> listB) {
        List<T> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
        returnObject.addAll(listA);
        returnObject.addAll(listB);
        return returnObject;
    }
```

This throws a compilation error I understand:

```
inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
```

I tried removing the equality constraint doing something like this:

```
    public static List<? extends Cake> union(List<? extends Cake> listA, List<? extends Cake> listB) {
        List<? extends Cake> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
        returnObject.addAll(listA);
        returnObject.addAll(listB);
        return returnObject;
    }
```

I guess this is a rather basic scenario for Java Generics, what would be the right way of getting this right?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: The `T`'s aren't all the same, so don't use the same letter. What you really need is more like `public static List<Cake> union(List<T extends Cake> listA, List<U extends Cake> listB)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the return type to `List<Cake>` and your second version should work fine:

```
public static List<Cake> union(List<? extends Cake> listA, List<? extends Cake> listB) {
    List<Cake> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
    returnObject.addAll(listA);
    returnObject.addAll(listB);
    return returnObject;
}
```

If you want the option to return some common subtype of `Cake`, you can combine the wildcard with the generic parameter:

```
public static <T extends Cake> List<T> union(List<? extends T> listA, List<? extends T> listB) {
    List<T> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
    returnObject.addAll(listA);
    returnObject.addAll(listB);
    return returnObject;
}
```

Comment: Tested both approaches and worked fine 

Answer (score 2):

Your existing code can only union two lists of exactly the same type. However you can change your type signature (the rest of the code can be left unchanged) to

```
public static <T extends Cake> List<T> union(
    List<? extends T> listA, List<? extends T> listB
)
```

In that case, you're saying that the two lists can be of any type, as long as that type is a subtype of `T`, which is a subtype of `Cake`.

Comment: Tested and worked fine 

Answer (score 1):

```
package cake;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {


    public static List<Cake> unionB(List<Cake> listA, List<Cake> listB) {
        List<Cake> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
        returnObject.addAll(listA);
        returnObject.addAll(listB);
        return returnObject;
    }

    public static List<Cake> unionC(List<ChocolateCake> listA, List<VanillaCake> listB) {
        List<Cake> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
        returnObject.addAll(listA);
        returnObject.addAll(listB);
        return returnObject;
    }

    public static List<Cake> unionD(List<? extends Cake> listA, List<? extends Cake> listB) {
        List<Cake> returnObject = new ArrayList<>();
        returnObject.addAll(listA);
        returnObject.addAll(listB);
        return returnObject;
    }

    public static void setB() {

        List<Cake> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(new ChocolateCake());

        List<Cake> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add(new VanillaCake());

        unionB(a, b);
    }

    public static void setC() {

        List<ChocolateCake> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(new ChocolateCake());

        List<VanillaCake> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add(new VanillaCake());

        unionC(a, b);
    }

    public static void setD() {

        List<ChocolateCake> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add(new ChocolateCake());

        List<VanillaCake> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add(new VanillaCake());

        unionD(a, b);
    }
}
```

This three method is also work.

1. unionB, unionC, unionD parameter type depends on your real parameter, when we need type like `? extends T`, generally there is a container, and the container need keep different type inherit from T. In this case, T is Cake.
2. `? extends T` container can not update, so your second method will cause compile error.
3. you change the three method return type to List<? extends Cake>